# Trying to get a file name or directory from a Python3 global class and then execute that using bash script

Tags: python-3.x, linux, bash

1. I have a globals.py file that I would like to store pertinent info for the entire system like directory locations, paths to python3 services/scripts etc.
2. I start these services on boot up using a bash shell script, however I need to retrieve the service locations from my global class enumerations.

I keep getting shell ERROR:
**python3: can't open file 'path/to/service.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory**

```
**globals.py** 

#contains a dictionary:
SERVICE_MAP = {
    'test': '~/path/to/service.py',
    'test2': '$HOME/path/to/service.py',
    'test3': '/full/path/to/service.py',
}
```

I have tried all the above forms of paths to the services. and the method of retrieval is:

```
**launch.sh**

function get_service() {
   python3 -c "import common.globals as gbl; print(gbl.SERVICE_MAP['$1'])"
}
```

And then call:

```
**launch.sh**

service=$(get_service "test")  # get service "test"
echo $service  #Output: is what it should be... "path/to/service.py"

# but when I now do:

python3 $service
#or
python3 "$service"

Output is always:
python3: can't open file '/path/to/service.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `~/path/to/service.py` != `path/to/service.py` != `/path/to/service.py` ... which of these is it?  I'd personally expect the highest probability of success from the format of test3 ...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the full path in the `globals.py` I put the relative path:

```
SERVICE_MAP = {
    'test': '/rel/path/to/service.py',
}
```

And in my `launch.sh` script I prepend `$HOME`:

```
function get_service() {
   python3 -c "import common.globals as gbl; print(gbl.SERVICE_MAP['$1'])"
}
python3 "$HOME$(get_service "test")"
```

I like this best because the `$HOME` user may change someday... Answered my own question, thanks for looking!